# How can I unlock the bootloader for my Moto G [Verizon Pre-Paid]

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, bootloader, motorola-moto-g, downgrade

I've had this phone for 2 years, the moto g 1st gen with verizon prepaid. ive looked everywhere. theres no way to unlock the bootloader, atleast not that I've found. I've searched everywhere on the XDA forums.

I'm trying to unlock it so that I can downgrade my phone from 5.x to 4.x.

I've tried temp rooting it with kingo root, towelroot, towelpieroot and kingroot, and i guess it doesn't support 5.1..

is there any way to unlock the bootloader? or even temp root so i can downgrade? thanks

Comment: So you first use a "one click root" untrusted Chinese app that probably contains malware and after that you want to downloaded to a previous Android build that it's guarantee to not have the latest security updates because...?

Comment: None of the "unofficial" methods work, in fact, I can't tell you how many phones have been bricked due to those "one-click root" tools. The only way is unlock bootloader via Moto, and use TWRP to flash SuperSU. All other methods that do not require an unlocked bootloader will fail.

Comment: On the Moto G series (all of them) downgrading is dangerous and not supported and the bootloader MUST be unlocked. After downgrad, the bootloader and ROM mismatch in version because the bootloader cannot be downgraded. Once in this state OTA updates fail with a potential to brick and should never be accepted. This is all a mute point if you can't use the official unlock from Moto, it is the ONLY way to unlock the bootloader, which I don't believe is supported on the Verizon model but feel free to try it: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a

Answer (score 1):

#### Hello Donavon

You need to know that all Moto Gs (GSM) shipped with locked bootloaders, even if you buy one that is factory SIM-Unlocked, but motorolla offers a way to unlock bootloaders on their phone for free after you register it and request an unlock code. Doing this will void your warranty especially in U.S..


So the question isn't whether or not the Verizon model will have a locked bootloader or not. It surely will, as they all do. The question is whether Motorola's on-line bootloader unlocker will work with Verizon-branded CDMA model or not. And at this point, given that it hasn't been released yet and nobody has one, how is anybody supposed to answer that question?

--- >credits Nathan from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2594691

Comment: Well formed answer but missing the final punch: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a